# Unable Retrive data from Firebase in the right format

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

i'm trying to get data from Firebase, but i'm unable to get them in the right format. The database is the following:

[image]

and here there is the code:

```
enter class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
val temperature = database.child("temperature").orderByKey().limitToLast(1)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    var textView = findViewById(R.id.viewTemperatura) as TextView

    val messageListener = object : ValueEventListener {

        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                val message = dataSnapshot.value.toString()
                textView.text= message
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            // Failed to read value
        }
    }

    temperature!!.addValueEventListener(messageListener)
}
```

When i get value from datasnapshot, i get a string like this: {-LQk8OYCk1jJNqFJTt0t={value=20.53}} but i'd like to get only the number. How can i do it without manipulate string directly?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try the following: `val message = dataSnapshot.child("value").value`